# How to escape space in script shell sh for defaults write value?

Tags: git, shell, plist

I want to write something in my plist, for that I use script shell.
I'm training on shell script on the same time.
I just try to get the three first output line of git log command, and put the output in property of info.plist

my script :

```
output=$(git log | head -n 3)
file=$(echo $PWD)/info 

# write it to the Info.plist
defaults write "$file" gitLog $output
```

the output of this command : $(git log | head -n 3)

```
commit glfdkjglkjdfgjdflkjglkdfjglkdfgkljdfk 
Author: Steve Jobs <steve.jobs@apple.com> 
Date: Fri Jun 28 14:33:38 2013 -0700
```

The problem is when I put `$output` for the parameter of `defaults write`. It thinks that I give commit with other parameters as "glfdkjglkjdfgjdflkjglkdfjglkdfgkljdfk" ...

So I need to do something make him understand that the output is just one argument.

It's like when I want to display the list of a folder with a name that content a space.
I have to do :

```
ls "MY FOLDER"
```

I hope I explained well my problem

help please

Comment: You're quoting `$file`, why not `$output`?

Comment: When I quote `output` it tells me that he can't parse the result of output, and after it says : Try single-quoting it.
I tried single quoting, it does nothing, my property is empty :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
output=$(git log | head -n 3)
file=$(echo $PWD)/info 

defaults write "$file" gitLog -string "$output"
```

if you want store 3 lines of text as "one string".

Or the next:

```
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
declare -a output=( $(git log | head -n 3) )
IFS=$OIFS

file=$(echo $PWD)/info 
defaults write "$file" gitLog -array "${output[0]}" "'${output[1]}'" "${output[2]}"
```

if you want store 3 lines as "array".

Comment: The first solution worked pretty well !
Thank you! I've just had to add -string argument!
Perfect!